# Can total internal reflection be used to create a source of light which will never be used up?

Tags: optics, energy-conservation, reflection, perpetual-motion

I am a science student and was thinking of something great for a science model , Thought of this, please tell me will this work and also suggest some other ideas that can be used to make good working model kind of thing;

Q ) Can we create something transparent where we can trap the light with TIR and use it as a source of light which will be never used up, like the light will be therein trapped forever but will give us some kind of energy or so;
thinks it is kind of silly and impossible;

Comment: The device you are describing would violate energy conservation and so is impossible

Answer (score 1):

#### No.

The device you're describing is a [perpetual-motion machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) and it is therefore (like all such devices) impossible.

In particular, if you managed to engineer your device such that light cannot escape (which would also mean that light cannot enter, since electromagnetism is time-reversible, but never mind that), then it would be incapable of working as a light source since the light cannot escape.

Comment: got your point, knew this was not possible but can you please explain what this means "which would also mean that light cannot enter, since electromagnetism is time-reversible, but never mind that". i mean i wan to know more about this

Comment: If you knew this was not possible, then why did you ask?

Comment: The phrase you highlight means that, basically, if your box is hermetically sealed such that X cannot get out, then X cannot get in unless there is some special asymmetry between "getting in" and "getting out", and no such asymmetry exists for electromagnetism.